# Returning values from for loops

Tags: loops, rust, return

So I have a for loop in my program and currently, it needs to return a value .

```
for (i, line) in br.lines().enumerate() {
            let string: String = line.unwrap().to_string();
            println!("line -> {}", string);
            full = format!("{}{}", full, string);
            println!("{}", full);

            counter += 1;
            return string;
        };
        println!("{}", string);
```

However, when I run it, it says, `expected (), found String`. My question is, how do I specify which type of data do I want to return from the for loop.

Comment: Where should they be "returned" to? It's not clear from the provided code.

Comment: You never return values from `for` loops directly. Your `for` loop code must be in a function or a closure.

Comment: If this were in a function, the `for` loop body could execute a maximum of one time because of the `return` statement, so it's not clear exactly what you intend for this loop to even do. It's not really a loop as written, it's more like an `if` block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I kinda like to think [`Iterator::fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) returns a value from a loop

Answer (score 0):

You want to include a return type in your function definition, like so:

```
fn my_function() -> String { // <-- return type
  // your code
}
```